# Renderblock JS and CSS Issue - W3 Total cache plugin

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, render

I'm using W3 Total Cache plugin on WP 4.3.1 for minifying Js and CSS for "above the fold" pagespeed requirements.

I managed to minify most of the stuff without a problem, this is what's left -

`jquery.js` > can be minfied in async after `<body>`, otherwise it breaks the site, if minified this way pagespeed generates another file named default.include-body.8853b0.js which can be minified but does not dissapear in pagespeed.

CSS

```
js_composer.css
bootstrap.min.css
revolution-styles.css
style.css
vivaco-animations.css
```

These can be mnified, but get the layout messed up in one way or another.

What's the best way to minify the rest?

Comment: well, all that messing would be due to one or two files, try minifying files one by one and then see which one is causing the issue, just ignore it from minifying by w3 total cache.

Comment: My bad, I was talking about render blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Minifying files is best using task runner such as gruntjs. You can pick what you want to minify in order.

You can learn more about gruntjs here: http://gruntjs.com/plugins

Comment: My bad, I was talking about render blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Google Pagespeed returns minified css and js when you analyze your website, you will find a download link at the bottom of the page. This works well for me as my pages still remain the same after optimization. 
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=your_web_url_here

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the jquery.js has to be set to defer, asyncing it does not work.

I did that with this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/async-javascript/